# How to adjust the number of processes of a Pool in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Is there a way to adjust the number of processes of a `multiprocessing.Pool` after it has been created? If not, what would be a correct way of implementing such functionality?

Comment: Do you have a sample of what you have already tried?

Comment: If you need more workers, then maybe the processes could spawn in threads to help them out? Processes can also spawn in other Processes, so long as they are not a daemon process...

Comment: @Reedinationer: Is there a solution for the case when I need less workers?

Comment: @JadieldeArmas I would just spawn less to begin with, and then have them make more as needed.

Comment: I am thinking of a case of adaptive computation, when I will be adjusting the number up or down in an adaptive way.

Comment: It might be a decent amount of work, seeing that you'd need to change some other stuff like `self._pool` in addition to the int `self._processes`.  See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3993ccb6820d4239ce3d9e1c5d31f13b86e0000b/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L183

Answer (score 1):

From the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3993ccb6820d4239ce3d9e1c5d31f13b86e0000b/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L302) there's a private method called `_repopulate_pool()` which seems to be able to change the number of workers in the pool. But I don't recommend you try to adjust the number of processors in a pool on-the-fly. You're better off just initializing the number of processors at the beginning.

To adjust the number of processes to use in `multiprocessing.Pool` you can use the `processes` flag. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool):

> `processes` is the number of worker processes to use. If `processes` is `None` then the number returned by `cpu_count()` is used.

For instance to set the number of processes to 4, which means that the `Pool` class will only allow 4 processes running at the same time.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
```